# Undefined variable error when uploading image to wampserver

Tags: php, html

I would need some advice/assistance here. I'm trying to upload image but wampserver keeping showing me this error (Notice: Undefined variable: name in C:\wamp\www\Shopaholic\upload_file.php on line 32), would appreciate if anyone can assist here. Thanks

here is my code

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>




<?php



if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$name       = $_FILES['file']['name'];  
$temp_name  = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];  
if(isset($name)){
    if(!empty($name)){      
        $location = '..Shopaholic/upload/';      
        if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $location.$name)){
            echo 'uploaded';
        }
    }       
}  else {
    echo 'please uploaded';
}
}


$sql1= mysql_query("INSERT INTO dumimage (name)values('$name')");

?>
```

this is the error line 32: `$sql1= mysql_query("INSERT INTO dumimage (name)values('$name')");`

Comment: Does `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` pass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your query in your IF statement. If it doesn't exist you can't use it. I'd put it after your file is uploaded and confirmed as succeeding. (Might want to check your IF statements, too. Not sure all of them are necessary).

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("shopaholic",$conn) or die (mysql_error());

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $name       = $_FILES['file']['name'];  
    $temp_name  = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];  
    if(isset($name)){
        if(!empty($name)){      
            $location = '..Shopaholic/upload/';      
            if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $location.$name)){
                echo 'uploaded';
                $sql1= mysql_query("INSERT INTO dumimage (name)values('$name')"); 
            }
        }       
    }  else {
        echo 'please uploaded';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: thank you John conde, the error didn't show up anymore. I think still very weak on my php code.